# Sending additional email from a YouTrack workflow

Tags: youtrack

Our doc writer would like to automatically receive an email from YouTrack whenever an issue in YouTrack has its status changed to Ready for Testing. She'd like this to happen without taking action on her part. This email would be in addition to the one already received by our QA lead (the Assignee). I wasn't able to find a way for her to receive the same email as our QA lead automatically, so I went down the workflow path.

I have created the following workflow:

```
when issue.State becomes({Ready for Testing}) {

var issueID = issue.getId();
var sumry = issue.summary;
var subject = "[YouTrack, Ready for Testing] Issue " + issueID + ": " + sumry;

var body = issueID + " is now ready for testing.<p>";
var linkText = issueID + " " + sumry;
body = body + "<a href=" + issue.getUrl() + ">" + linkText + "</a><p>"
body = body + issue.comments.last.text;

var docWriter = project.getUser("docwriter");
docWriter.notify(subject, body);
}
```

The workflow works and the doc writer receives messages. However, our QA lead no longer receives the built in messages. It *seems* that when a YouTrack workflow sends a message, other messages that would automatically get sent to the Assignee are skipped. Is there a way to get them both to send?

Alternatively, is there another approach within YouTrack to meet this requirement of two people automatically receiving an e-mail (the Assignee and someone else). I don't want our doc writer to have to watch every issue as she will get extra, unnecessary e-mails and action will be required on her part.

Comment: The workflow is correct and generally speaking notifications should not interfere with workflow. It seems to be a bug, you can report it here:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JT#newissue=yes . As a workaround I can suggest to add to this workflow QA, i.e.: var QA = project.getUser("QA");
QA.notify(subject, body);

Comment: Thanks for the response and confirmation that it seems to be a bug. I am using the workaround you suggested. I will submit it as a bug.